# Uncompress Z files and then delete the files after in a script

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to uncompress Z files in a directory and then delete them afterwards (but keep the original Z files). What is the best way of going about doing this?

Thanks!

EDITED: If the Z files are deleted after uncompressing, how can I compress them-- they're quite a lot. An idea: is it possible to uncompress the files into a folder and then afterwards just compress that folder back into a Z file?

Comment: Its not clear what you're doing with the files after you uncompress them (besides recompressing them). If you're just temporarily looking inside the file with grep, you can do something like `uncompress -c ${file} | grep srchTarget | sed "s/^/$file:/" > srchResults.txt` and avoid having to mess with recompressing. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! They are actually reports that I need to print. :/

Comment: Consider editing your question to include what command(s) you will be applying to you the files. There may be other tricks to avoid recompressing. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Unix `uncompress` automatically deletes the compressed file when the file is uncompressed.  If you want to preserve the compressed file and uncompress it as well, create a copy of the file and uncompress that copy:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.Z; do

echo $file

#copy to temporary file and uncompress
cp $file tmp.Z
uncompress tmp.Z

#rename uncompressed temp file to match original name
mv ${file%.*} $file

done
```

Note that `compress` can only work on one file at a time.  If you need to compress several files together, then you can use `tar`.  For example, you can modify the above script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir tmp

for file in *.Z; do
mv $file tmp/
uncompress tmp/$file
done

tar -cf files.tar tmp/*
compress files.tar
rm -r tmp
```

What this script now does is this:

1) create temporary directory under the current one
2) uncompresses all .Z files into that directory
3) removes all .Z files (`uncompress` does it automatically)
4) combines all the files together into `files.tar` archive
5) compresses the archive into `files.tar.Z`
6) deletes uncompressed files and the temporary directory